# Как сделать MultiValueField с полями (SelectField и MultipleChoiceField) по типу MultipleChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, forms

Стоит задача получить поле вот такого вида:
[image: Пример]

Почитав документацию, нашел информацию о поле MultiValueField и виджете MultiWidget, с помощью которых можно это провернуть. Но у меня получается вывести только одно поле с выбором.
Мои классы - класс виджета:

```
class ChoiceWithDescriptionWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
allow_multiple_selected = True

def __init__(self, attrs=None, chkbx_attrs=None, txt_attrs=None):
    wdgts = (widgets.CheckboxInput(), widgets.Select(choices=IS_USTU_CHOISE))
    super(ChoiceWithDescriptionWidget, self).__init__(widgets=wdgts, attrs=attrs)

def decompress(self, value):
    return value or (None, None)
```

Класс поля:

```
class ChoiseFieldWithDescriptionField(MultiValueField):
widget = ChoiceWithDescriptionWidget()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    flds = (ChoiceField(), MultipleChoiceField())
    super(ChoiseFieldWithDescriptionField, self).__init__(flds, *args, **kwargs)
```

В итоге получается такое поле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как сделать по типу MultipleChoiceField, чтобы выводило полный список Названий и Параметров для них? Я понимаю, что нужно переопределить метод, но не понятно, у чего - у виджета или поля.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно будет написать виджет, унаследованный от `forms.MultiWidget`, в котором вы определите метод `__init__`, с нужными типами виджетов, `decompress` и, возможно, `value_from_datadict`. Можно скопировать `render` из `MultiWidget` и переделать под свои нужды.

Далее нужно будет определить свой тип поля, унаследованный от `forms.MultiValueField`. В нём нужно будет указать атрибут `widget`, с созданным вами виджетом, и определить методы `__init__` и `compress`.